# Javascript copy nested array within object array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have the following state object.

```
 list: [
      {
        "_id":"1","category":"Cat 1",
        "subcategory":[
          {"_id":"2","subcat":"Subcat 1"},
        ]
      },
      {"_id":"2","category":"Cat 2"},
    ],
```

I want to modify the values of _id:1.  I make a copy of the object I need using:

```
let listCopy = list.filter(el => el._id == 1)
```

and then:

```
let subList = listCopy.subcategory.slice();
```

Why do I keep getting undefined for subList? What are some options for making a copy of the nested object?

Comment: Just FYI `filter` is not making copies of your objects. Not related to your issue but I'm dropping this anyway.

Comment: It's because `listCopy` is an **array**, and your object will be found in `listCopy[0]`

Comment: Given you're using ES2015, you might have used `Array.prototype.find`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method returns an array and you expect an object. You can try `listCopy[0].subcategory.slice();` if you just want one element.

Comment: Ah! I see.  My oversight

Answer (score 0):

The result is an array, so you need: `listCopy[0]....`

```js
var list = [
      {
        "_id":"1",
        "category":"Cat 1",
        "subcategory":[
          {"_id":"2","subcat":"Subcat 1"},
        ]
      },
      {"_id":"2",
       "category":"Cat 2"
      }
    ];

let listCopy = list.filter(el => el._id == 1)  // Result is an array
let subList = listCopy[0].subcategory.slice(); // <-- Need to use index
console.log(subList);
```